# Some weird code in i686-w64-mingw32/include/shlobj.h

Tags: c, archlinux, openal

I was building openal for mingw-gcc

`$ yaourt -S mingw-w64-openal`

and got a syntax error:

```
[ 38%] Building C object CMakeFiles/OpenAL32.dir/Alc/alcConfig.c.obj
In file included from /tmp/yaourt-tmp-hacked/aur-mingw-w64-openal/src/openal-soft-1.16.0/Alc/alcConfig.c:36:0:
/usr/i686-w64-mingw32/include/shlobj.h:37:3: error: unknown type name ‘EXTERN_C’
   SHFOLDERAPI SHGetFolderPathW (HWND hwnd, int csidl, HANDLE hToken, DWORD dwFlags, 
   ^
/usr/i686-w64-mingw32/include/shlobj.h:37:3: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘HRESULT’
   SHFOLDERAPI SHGetFolderPathW (HWND hwnd, int csidl, HANDLE hToken, DWORD dwFlags, 
   ^
/usr/i686-w64-mingw32/include/shlobj.h:37:3: error: unknown type name ‘HRESULT’
CMakeFiles/OpenAL32.dir/build.make:463: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/OpenAL32.dir/Alc/alcConfig.c.obj' failed
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/OpenAL32.dir/Alc/alcConfig.c.obj] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:60: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/OpenAL32.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/OpenAL32.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:116: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

i've looked into this `shlobj.h` on line 37 and found this:

```
typedef enum {
  SHGFP_TYPE_CURRENT = 0,
  SHGFP_TYPE_DEFAULT = 1,
} SHGFP_TYPE;

  SHFOLDERAPI SHGetFolderPathW (HWND hwnd, int csidl, HANDLE hToken, DWORD dwFlags, LPWSTR pszPath);
```

I'm not a pro in C, but seems like `}` is inside a enum block, so i've tried to fix it all the ways possible, but without success.

Comment: What version of mingw. Also did you `#include <windows.h>` before including shlobj?  Can you post a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @MattMcNabb how to check that?
where should i include this header?
i was just making `yaourt -S mingw-w64-openal`

Comment: If you're wondering if it's the extra comma in the enum definition, that's actually allowed.. and the `}` is fine where it is.  `SHFOLDERAPI` is probably a macro with `EXTERN_C` in its expansion, which is probably not defined for some reason -- missing header?

Comment: @Dmitri, okay then the syntax is correct, how can i fix this?

Comment: check this out - http://sourceforge.net/p/mingw-w64/bugs/476/

Comment: @Abhi, awesome, thnx a lot. Why they havent patched it yet? How to make this solved?

Comment: Option #1 check the patch provided at that link - you have to rebuild -  Option #2 Try to pull the version that has the patch included

Comment: @Abhi, oh lol, a bit of misunderstanding, ive already fixed this syntax error. I was asking how to mark this question solved, coz im new to stackoverflow.

Comment: I have posted it in answer form below - please will push the counter up 1 and then click on accept as answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check this out - http://sourceforge.net/p/mingw-w64/bugs/476

- Option #1 check the patch provided at that link - you have to rebuild
- Option #2 Try to pull the version that has the patch included